# SG90 not responding with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I bought an SG90 servo motor, seller demonstrated by direct supply check, it works there but with Arduino servo sweep check it does not respond: no error during compiling and uploading, but it does not respond.

While other Arduino examples are working correctly like blink example. 
I have changed another one but result is the same.

Neither it moves by Arduino nor after installing a grbl shield, where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Please, post your arduino sketch and schematic connections.

Comment: Even a small servo motor requires a lot of current. You could add a power supply. Do you use a good quality usb cable? The component on the right of the arduino board, with the golden stripes is a polyfuse of 500mA. That servo motor can draw 500mA or more.

Comment: Leoc 7, I have already attached a picture.

Comment: @AdnanTahir please post your code. As Leoc7 said, usually powering servos from the Arduino directly isn't the best idea, but in my personal projects I've powered several servos from my arduino, as long as they weren't under any load :)

Comment: Arduino can readily power an SG90 servo under no load in my own experience. Also see [this question on Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246642/power-supply-circuit-for-powering-sg90-servo-how-to-handle-high-current-require). If you're seeing no response, there is a fault in the wiring, the code, or the servo itself.

I think I'm seeing the servo's signal wire (orange) connected to the yellow wire to pin 9. Is your sketch attaching pin 9? What is the brown wire connected to the Arduino near the servo's power & ground (red & black)?

Comment: @JRobert those servos use Orange for Sig, Brown for GND and Red for Vcc. I use them all the time in my RC projects, and haven't had any issues using Arduinos either. My guess is coding, we'll see if he posts it or not

Comment: OP has issue when using *Arduino servo sweep* - it's an example in the Servo library - it uses pin 9 for Signal ... so I dare say it should work unless OP modified the example (highly doubt it)

Comment: Friends, I did not modify code even a litte bit, I uninstalled arduino and reinstalled but whenever I tried the code servo did not rotate, however no error occurred in compile and upload. The code is same in the arduino IDE Examples >Servo >Sweep. I wanted to ask if there is a possibility of any fault in my arduino board 5v, gnd or signal pin. Because servo with direct 5v battery power supply is rotating that means servo is fine. I watched several videos regarding sg90 test with arduino uno and same I have been trying to do but the outcome is NO ROTATION as I have mentioned in my query.

Comment: I always tried arduino IDE menu option i.e. Examples > Servo > Sweep, I did not try any thing manually or a self written code. Wiring is accurate as shown in my attached picture. I wanted to know that is there any action missing or it is a confirmed board fault.

Comment: Then your next step should be to measure the 5v with a DVM: at the 3-pin connector with- and without the servo connected to it, and at the Arduino pin the connector is plugged-in to. Maybe all of the Arduino 5v pins (without the servo connected) if everything else wasn't what it should be (5v +/- a few millivolts).

Comment: @HavocRC: I may be confused by a shadow, but it looks rather like there are 3 conductors connected to the top row of the board and a 4-th one to the bottom (pin 9).

Comment: @AdnanTahir we know these servos work fine with Arduinos, and since the wiring is correct, here's all that could be wrong: Broken 5v rail from Arduino, broken PWM pin on 9, or a faulty servo. You can even measure with your DMM if the P9 is putting out the proper PWM frequency/duty cycle.